# No connection adapters were found for 'itms-appss:/

Tags: python, python-3.x

No connection adapters were found for 'itms-appss://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fiverr-freelance-services/id346080608?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4'

I am scraping apps info from apple app store. I keep running through this few minutes into the scraping.

```
with open('App_Store_Links.csv', newline='') as f_urls, open('appsinfo.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
csv_output.writerow(['App Name', 'Category','Size','Developer','Age Rating','Rating','Rating Numbers'])
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'


for line in csv_urls:
    r = requests.get(line[0].strip(),headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    for i, x in enumerate(line):
        x = x.replace("itms-appss","https")
        line[i] = x

    try:
        app_name = soup.find('h1', class_='product-header__title app-header__title').text
        Category = soup.findAll('dd', class_='information-list__item__definition l-column medium-9 large-6')[2].text
        Size = soup.findAll('dd', class_='information-list__item__definition l-column medium-9 large-6')[1].text
        Developer = soup.findAll('dd', class_='information-list__item__definition l-column medium-9 large-6')[0].text
        Age_Rating = soup.find('span', class_='badge badge--product-title').text
        Price = soup.find('li', class_='inline-list__item inline-list__item--bulleted app-header__list__item--price').text
        Rating_number = soup.find('div', class_='we-customer-ratings__count small-hide medium-show').text
        Rating = soup.find('span', class_='we-customer-ratings__averages__display').text
    except Exception:
        pass



    csv_output.writerow([app_name,Category,Size,Developer,Age_Rating,Rating,Rating_number])
```

then I get this error when I run the code. 
p.s none of the links inside App_Store_Links.csv have any itms-appss urls, so i'm not sure whats happening

`No connection adapters were found for 'itms-appss://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fiverr-freelance-services/id346080608?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4'`

Answer (score 0):

fixed by setting allow_redirects to false in the reguests code

```
r = requests.get(line[0].strip(),allow_redirects=False,headers=headers).text
```